# Not get response in magento like query

Tags: magento-1.9

```
$model = Mage::getResourceModel('test/test')
                    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('title'))
                    -> array('like' => $_POST['data'].' %')
                    ->getCollection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do code like this one :

```
$model = Mage::getResourceModel('test/test')
->addAttributeToSelect('title'->array('like' => $_POST['data'].' %') ->getCollection();
```